# Evaluate multiple conditions stored as a string

Tags: php, string, evaluation

I have a few strings stored in a database which contain specific rules which must be met. The rules are like this:

```
>25
>25 and < 82
even and > 100
even and > 10 or odd and < 21
```

Given a number and a string, what is the best way to evaluate it in PHP?

eg. Given the number 3 and the string "even and > 10 or odd and < 21" this would evaluate to TRUE

Thanks

Mitch

Comment: Ive been looking at eval() and some regex expressions but nothing seems to quite fit what Im looking for. Im trying to avoid having to do heaps of comparisions. ie if str[0] == ">" then ...

Comment: There is no general solution to your problem. It can be complex or simple. (I would try to keep it simple). However, you can have a look at the php parser generator an lexer packages, tutorial: http://blog.oncode.info/2007/10/25/eine-eigene-programmiersprache-erschaffen-lexer-und-parser-in-php/  (german, but seeing the code should be a starting point)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the solution to this can be very simple or very complex.

I've thrown together a function that will work with the examples you've given:

```
function ruleToExpression($rule) {
    $pattern = '/^( +(and|or) +(even|odd|[<>]=? *[0-9]+))+$/';
    if (!preg_match($pattern, ' and ' . $rule)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid expression');
    }
    $find = array('even', 'odd', 'and', 'or');
    $replace = array('%2==0', '%2==1', ') && ($x', ')) || (($x');
    return '(($x' . str_replace($find, $replace, $rule) . '))';
}

function evaluateExpr($expr, $val) {
    $x = $val;
    return eval("return ({$expr});");
}
```

This supports multiple clauses separated by `and` and `or`, with no parentheses and the `and` always being evaluated first. Each clause can be `even`, `odd`, or a comparison to a number, allowing `>`, `<`, `>=`, and `<=` comparisons.

It works by comparing the entire rule against a regular expression pattern to ensure its syntax is valid and supported. If it passes that test, then the string replacements that follow will successfully convert it to an executable expression hard-coded against the variable `$x`.

As an example:

```
ruleToExpression('>25');
// (($x>25))

ruleToExpression('>25 and < 82');
// (($x>25 ) && ($x < 82))

ruleToExpression('even and > 100');
// (($x%2==0 ) && ($x > 100))

ruleToExpression('even and > 10 or odd and < 21');
// (($x%2==0 ) && ($x > 10 )) || (($x %2==1 ) && ($x < 21))

evaluateExpr(ruleToExpression('even and >25'), 31);
// false

evaluateExpr(ruleToExpression('even and >25'), 32);
// true

evaluateExpr(ruleToExpression('even and > 10 or odd and < 21'), 3);
// true
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you translate the string `even` to maths? If you use mods you can write it like that `$number % 2 == 0`. In that case, your example will be:

```
if(($number % 2 == 0 && $number > 10 ) || ($number % 2 != 0 && $number < 21)){
//Then it is true!
}
```

Comment: I know how to use mods, but how do generate the php code above given only a string?